# Voip push not received in ios device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

I want to add voip push support for my application. I followed the steps in the [link](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/) . On sending the push from huston it says "1 push notification sent successfully". I tried the same using amazon sns it says the same that push is published successfully, but i don't see the push being received at the registry delegate i.e. *didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload*. I tried this using the voip distribution profile. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Posssible reasons:

1. Your .pem certificate may be wrong.
2. Your BundleId may be wrong.
3. Your Device id may be wrong.

> Note: Append .voip with your bundleid for sending voip push notification(exmple: bundleid.voip)

Here is an workable example of voip push notification :

```
<?php
$token = $_REQUEST['tok'];
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
  define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
}
// open connection 
$http2ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
// send push
$apple_cert = 'certificate_name.pem';
$message = '{"aps":{"action":"message","title":"your_title","body":"your_message_body"}}';
$http2_server = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com'; // or 'api.push.apple.com' if production
$app_bundle_id = 'your bundle id';
$status = sendHTTP2Push($http2ch, $http2_server, $apple_cert, $app_bundle_id, $message, $token);
echo $status;
// close connection
curl_close($http2ch);
function sendHTTP2Push($http2ch, $http2_server, $apple_cert, $app_bundle_id, $message, $token) 
{
    // url (endpoint)
    $url = "{$http2_server}/3/device/{$token}";
    $cert = realpath($apple_cert);
    // headers
    $headers = array(
        "apns-topic: {$app_bundle_id}",
        "User-Agent: My Sender"
    );
    curl_setopt_array($http2ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($http2ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
      throw new Exception("Curl failed: " .  curl_error($http2ch));
    }
    // get response
    $status = curl_getinfo($http2ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($status=="200")
    echo "SENT|NA";
    else
    echo "FAILED|$status";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is adding .voip to the end of the app bundle required? Also when i am calling this script i am getting `reason: 'Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.'` Is there maybe something i am missing?

Comment: Yes you have to add .voip with your bundle id - 
 Like - 
$app_bundle_id = 'yourbundleid.voip' ;

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html) is one link to follow the steps of VOIP.

When you will get any voip notification then **didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload** get invoke. You can notify user with local notification from there.

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried printing a log but it wasn't working. But on adding the local notification I see it working.

Answer (score -1):

Reference
https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Both Objective C and Swift code is there.

Just check certificates, code and sending voip ( silent ) pushnotification.

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

           
    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    
    self.PushKitRegistration()
    
    return true
}

//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{
    
    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        
        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
        
        // Set the registry's delegate to self
        
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        
        // Set the push type to VoIP
        
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    
}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server
    
    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
    
    print(hexString)
    
    
}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    
    
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```